# Python 3 -- using kwargs with an args only module

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, publish-subscribe, pypubsub

I am writing a gui in tkinter and using a publish/subscribe module (pyPubSub) to inform different parts of the program of what is occurring if they're subscribed.  So, I have two functions that I need to work together.  From tkinter, I'm using:

```
after_idle(callback, *args)
```

to call the message sending within the mainloop.  As you can see, it only accepts *args for the arguments to send to the callback.  The callback I'm sending is from pyPubSub:

```
sendMessage(topic, **kwargs)
```

So, I end up with this:

```
root.after_idle(pub.sendMessage, ?)
```

My question is, how do I make args work with kwargs?  I have to call after_idle with positional arguments to send with the callback, but the callback requires keyword arguments only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always use `lambda`, here's a short example that does nothing.

```
import tkinter as tk

def test(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)

root = tk.Tk()
root.after_idle(lambda: test(arg1=1, arg2=2))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how that would fix it.  For example, I have gui_obj.after_idle(pub.sendMessage, *package) as it requires and package looks like this: [<topic name>, <arg1>], for instance (sometimes there are more than one arg, sometimes not, it doesn't work either way).  When after_idle registers the callback, it calls sendMessage(<topic name>, <arg1>) and I can't figure out how to get it to send it as sendMessage(<topic name>, msg=<arg1>) as sendMessage requires.  I keep getting: TypeError: sendMessage() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  I need to use lambda as the callback function that will then call sendMessage correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: The "takes 2 positional arguments" exception was caused by after_idle not sending it correctly.  sendMessage wanted 2 positional args (self and topic) and then kwargs.  after_idle was sending topic and the optional arguments both as positional so it was getting 3 positionals (1 of which is self) when it only wanted 2 (technically just one from me and 1 from itself)